# Anyone know the way to know the popup window which is opened by form is closed?

Tags: javascript, html

I opened the popup window in Javascript and want to get the event when it is closing.

```
// Main.js
const fnPopup = () => {
    var popup = window.open('', 'pChk', 'width=500, height=500, scrollbars=no, status=no, menubar=no');
    popup.onbeforeunload = () => {
        console.log("[NOTIFY] This Popup will be closed");
    };
};
```

Above code is working well. When popup is closed, TEST console log is printed.
**BUT I should submit the data by form** because some some authorization data should be sent. So I changed the code like below but it is not working well.

```
// Main.js
const fnPopup = () => {
    var popup = window.open('', 'pChk', 'width=500, height=500, scrollbars=no, status=no, menubar=no');
    popup.onbeforeunload = () => {
        console.log("[TEST] This Popup will be closed");
    };

    document.autho_form.action = "https://myAuthorizationSite.com/autho.cb"; // The site of Service Provider (Not our code)
    document.autho_form.target = "pChk";
    document.autho_form.submit();
};
```

In this case, above TEST console log is printed once while move to action site. But after page is moved, TEST log didn't printed although popup window is closed.

**SUMMARY: Can anybody help to teach the way to get the event when the popup window which is submitted by form is closed? Additionally, I should modify Main.js only. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: #1 What do you mean by "move to action site",  "after page is moved" #2 Do you need to open the classic popup (oauth2 flow) with a login form and then send the user/password to some http endpoint?

Comment: @JRichardsz, Thanks your question. #1: When popup is opened, popup window shows a blank page first and then move to "https://myAuthorizationSite.com/autho.cb". Action site and page what I mentioned means this url. (https://myAuthorizationSite.com/autho.cb) #2. To authorize, I should add some encoding data using Form for the popup and it is not a problem in this situation. I just want to get the notify event when this popup window is closed.